# How to deal with nested ng-template in Angular

Tags: angular, angular-components, ngx-datatable, ng-template, angular-dynamic-components

I am making a ngx-datatabel wraper and i want to pass the column template from the parent component. Which i am doing through ng-template outlet. But its not being rendered for some reason.

Here is how i am passing tempalate in parent

```
<app-list>
  <ng-template #customColumns>
    <ngx-datatable-column name="age" >
      <ng-template let-value="value" ngx-datatable-cell-template>
        Test
      </ng-template>
    </ngx-datatable-column>
  </ng-template>
</app-list>
```

Here is the child component html

```
<ngx-datatable [rows]="rows" [columns]="cols">

  <ng-container [ngTemplateOutlet]="customColumnsTemplate">
  </ng-container>

</ngx-datatable>
```

child component ts

```
@ContentChild('customColumns')
  customColumnsTemplate: TemplateRef<any>;
```

If i just copy paste the template directly in child component it works fine but its not working with ngTemplateOutlet.

Currently using Angular **10.1.6**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an array of columns which contain your templates. It can be an array of objects like so:

```
let columns = [{ name: "Column Name", cellTemplate: someCellTemplate, headerTemplate: someHeaderTemplate...}]
```

Template in this case would be the template in your app-list component.

```
 <ng-template #myCellTemplate let-row="row" let-column="column" let-value="value">
    Test
 </ng-template>
```

You access your template in the app-list component with ViewChild

```
@ViewChild('myCellTemplate') myCellTemplate: TemplateRef<any>;
```

Your child component is actually the ngx-datatable wrapper if I understood corectly, so you would only need to send the columns as an input to that wrapper.

```
<ngx-datatable [rows]="rows" [columns]="columns">
</ngx-datatable>
```

Example from their demos here [Ngx-datatable Examples](https://github.com/swimlane/ngx-datatable/blob/master/src/app/templates/template-obj.component.ts)

Documentation here [Doc](https://swimlane.gitbook.io/ngx-datatable/api/column/inputs)